# Correct usage for coreutils join and sort

Tags: sorting, join, command-line

I am trying to use the standard command-line tool `join` to join two files. According to the documentation, both input files need to be sorted for this. Initially I just piped them through `sort` to achieve this, but this still resulted in errors like "join: file 2 is not in sorted order". I then looked into this a bit more closely and found that I was supposed to use `sort -k 1b,1`, but that didn't seem to help either. I even played around with the locales (setting `LANG=C` or `LANG=EN_en`) but nothing seems to work.

So far I tried:

- `cat x | sort | join -j 1 a -`
- `cat x | sort -k1b,1 | join -j 1 a -`
- `cat x | LANG=C sort -k1b,1 | join -j 1 a -`
- `cat x | LANG=EN_en sort -k1b,1 | join -j 1 a -`

So, how do I use join correctly on unsorted files?

Comment: Show us how did you tried

Comment: Give a small sample of the data that reproduces the problem. It is hard to tell something definite otherwise.

Comment: I edited my question to show what I have tried so far. I will see if I can make a small test case.

Comment: `join` should tell you which line is out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Basically :

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```